# c++ set_intersection command, error c2064

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I wrote the code below to use the set_intersection command:
it compiles and runs well inside main() but when I try to run it inside a function within a class I get the following error:

```
Error   6   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 5 arguments    
8   IntelliSense: call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type
```

Please help me understand what is the problem, thanks

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int ra[] = { 12, 2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 1 };
int rb[] = { 1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 17 };
set<int> a(ra, ra + sizeof(ra) / sizeof(int));
auto result_1 = a.insert(17);

set<int> b(rb, rb + sizeof(rb) / sizeof(int));

set<int> c;

set_intersection(a.begin(), a.end(),
                 b.begin(), b.end(),
                 std::insert_iterator< std::set<int> >(c, c.begin()));
```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`std::inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter)

```
set_intersection(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::inserter(c, c.begin()));
```

Comment: I see my mistake, I had a definition: set_base set_intersection; at the beginning of the function so I was calling my own struct. thanks